# Upload camera preview android

Tags: php, android

I try to show camera preview in SurfaceView and upload that preview to my website. Something like a wireless webcam. Preview is displayed in surfaceView fine but it seem to be cannot upload to my website, i receive nothing in my website. Here is my code in android

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder holder;
 private Camera camera;
 String MyImage;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            try
            {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback()
                {
                    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera)
                    {
                        MyImage = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",MyImage));
                        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try{
                                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nns12151069.esy.es/upload_image.php");
                                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                            }
                        });
                        t.start();
                    }
                });
            }
             catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

and .php file which receive preview in website

```
 <?php
 $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
 header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
 $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
 fwrite($file, $binary);
 fclose($file);


 $path = "publib_html/"; 
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
 $size = $_FILES['file']['size']; 

 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$path.$name);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preview images are not normally JPEG images, and your server code seems to suggest that you think that they are. The actual format is based on what you supply to [`setPreviewFormat()` on `Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int)) and has to be one of the values from [`getSupportedPreviewFormats()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewFormats%28%29). Most likely you will wind up with `NV21` or `YV12`.